# move the maven-onejar generated jar to a custom location

Tags: maven-3, onejar

I am using the `onejar-maven-plugin` to generate the jar for my project and it all goes well. But, when I try to change it to a sub-folder, for eg. `dist`, the jar from `maven-jar-plugin` gets generated, not the jar from onejar.

The onejar plugin does not have an output directory option.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist</outputDirectory>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.ss.itempriceclient.ItemPriceUploader</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
    <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>onejar</classifier>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>one-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

How do I change the output directory of the onejar generated file to a subfolder, eg. `dist`?

Comment: Why do you need to change the folder inside target folder? Why defining a outputDirectory for maven-jar-plugin? If you like to create a single jar which contains all dependencies just take a look at maven-assembly-plugin which handles this.

Comment: Thats what I finally did. I think this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went with `maven-assembly-plugin`. Has lots of configuration options.